# How do I access a method that's inside a python inner class?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sessions extension to store user sessions in the database and now trying to query this table to get stored sessions. The session table is created the following way,

```
SqlAlchemySessionInterface(app, db, table='Session', key_prefix='')
```

now I'd like to get all the entries using the model query call like this,

```
Session.query.all()
```

But I am not able to do that due to the fact that the Session class in a inner class of the SqlAlchemySessionInterface class. Any idea how I can go about querying the table?

The complete SqlAlchemySessionInterface class code below,

```
class SqlAlchemySessionInterface(SessionInterface):

    serializer = pickle
    session_class = SqlAlchemySession

    def __init__(self, app, db, table, key_prefix, use_signer=False,
                 permanent=True):
        if db is None:
            from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
            db = SQLAlchemy(app)
        self.db = db
        self.key_prefix = key_prefix
        self.use_signer = use_signer
        self.permanent = permanent

        class Session(self.db.Model):
            __tablename__ = table

            id = self.db.Column(self.db.Integer, primary_key=True)
            session_id = self.db.Column(self.db.String(255), unique=True)
            data = self.db.Column(self.db.LargeBinary)
            expiry = self.db.Column(self.db.DateTime)

            def __init__(self, session_id, data, expiry):
                self.session_id = session_id
                self.data = data
                self.expiry = expiry

            def __repr__(self):
                return '<Session data %s>' % self.data

        # self.db.create_all()
        self.sql_session_model = Session
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, should have `from flask_session import Session` and `Session(app)`.

Bind the return object of `Session(app)` to an variable, such as `sess`.

Then, `session_model = sess._get_interface(app).sql_session_model`.

Then, you can `session_model.query.all()`.

**Key point**: look at the source code of Session.